# ERROR: column "exists" does not exist in SQL insert command

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I'm trying to learn about triggers a bit and I want to make a trigger that will check if im adding new row to my prediction table that made of (city,eventype,casualties)

that if my new row casualties number is higher than the city population i will get an error and the new row wont be inserted into my prediction table

here is my code so far

creating my Trigger

```
create trigger T1
before insert on prediction
for each row
execute procedure trigf1();
```

creating trigf1();

```
create or replace function trigf1() returns trigger as $$
declare bad_population record;
Begin
  select city.cname INTO bad_population
  from city
  where new.casualties>city.population and new.cname=city.cname;

  if exists bad_population then begin 
    raise notice 'bad population-more casualites than city population';
    return null;
  end;
  else
    return new;
  end if;
end;
$$language plpgsql;
```

im getting an error when i try to enter these values

```
insert into prediction values ('Naples', 'Volcano', 3056)
```

and this is the error

```
ERROR:  column "exists" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT exists bad_population
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT exists bad_population
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function trigf1() line 7 at IF
SQL state: 42703
```

my City Table

[image: my City Table]

my prediction table

[image: my prediction table]

would love your help understanding the error and solving my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FOUND`: `IF FOUND THEN`.

If there were any results from your query, `FOUND` will be TRUE, else FALSE.

`EXISTS` takes a query which returns TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the query returns any results, e.g. `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition) THEN...`

So the main difference is `FOUND` is a variable which is set after your query/statement returns, and is set to TRUE/FALSE depending on whether your SELECT statement returned any results, or your UPDATE/DELETE statement affected any rows.

`EXISTS` on the other hand is an operator that returns TRUE/FALSE based on a query you provide to it at that point in time.

Comment: thanks buddy that worked! 
have to wait 6 mins before accepting your answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation you made it pretty clear to me!

Comment: @dor (thumbsup)

Comment: Note: though the syntax looks function-like, EXISTS is an operator. `boolean := EXISTS '(' query-expression ')'`